# Youtube-dl Syntax

Tags: youtube-dl

I am using youtube-dl downloading videos and wish to number the videos and put them in relevant folders.  It does work however the numbered videos start with 000001 and continue upwards.  I want the videos to be in the hundreds. For example 001 and upwards.  I've looked everywhere for a solution.  It says the syntax is autonumber-size Number. I've used the following output template

```
youtube-dl -o "%(chapter_number)s - %(chapter)s/%(autonumber-size 3)s %(title)s.%(ext)s" -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD URL
```

This creates files being prefixed with NA instead of 001 and above.
Can anyone please help me.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`%(autonumber)03d`.

This is clearly explained in [youtube-dl's FAQ](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#output-template).